# How can i add firebase authentication to laravel api routes

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am new to laravel. I am using laravel default authentication for web routes but i want to authenticate api routes using firebase token.

I have got a package for authentication but i don't know how to properly use it
https://github.com/csrui/laravel-firebase-auth

i have added these

AuthserviceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->app['auth']->viaRequest('firebase', function ($request) {
        return app(\csrui\LaravelFirebaseAuth\Guard::class)->user($request);
    });

}
```

config/app.php (providers array)

```
csrui\LaravelFirebaseAuth\FirebaseAuthServiceProvider::class,
```

.env

```
FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=myprojectName //write your project id here
```

config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'firebase',
        'provider' => 'firebase',
    ],
],
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'firebase' => [
        'driver' => 'firebase',
        'model' => \csrui\LaravelFirebaseAuth\User::class,
    ],
],
```

When i make api request it with firebase token as authentication bearer . it doesn't work.
i feel like i am doing wrong in config/auth.php

Answer (score 3):

After debugging my api. I came to know that it works but there is error in ssl

cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Which i solved by downloading "cacert.pem" from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
 and copying to project base 
then added these lines to "\vendor\kreait\firebase-tokens\src\HttpKeyStore.php"

```
        'base_uri' => '57a/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src',
        'verify' => base_path('cacert.pem'),
```

Now everything works well.